# Looking for short story about a character briefly exposed to all levels of sensory input

Tags: story-identification

The main character (possibly a woman) is told by another character (possibly a shaman) that their perception of the universe is extremely limited but can be temporarily opened. The main character agrees to do this but is warned that the outcome will be psychologically damaging because they will see how limited their perceptions truly are.
I read this sometime in the late 60s early 70s.

Comment: This one? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Secret_Sense

Comment: As in Lovecraft's [From Beyond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/From_Beyond_(short_story))

Comment: If the sense is to see electric fields then it would be [The Secret Sense](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/229003/sci-fi-short-story-about-extra-sense-that-can-be-experienced-by-humans-only-once) by Asimov.